# Reformat JSON objects inside an array to show them in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js

I'm trying to find a way to reformat an array of JSON objects that looks like:

```
[{"amount":3,"name":"Coca-Cola"},{"amount":3,"name":"Rib Eye"}]
```

I want to only print the values in plain html text. For example:

```
3 - Coca-Cola
3 - Rib Eye
```

How can i achieve this? My back end is Node.js so yeah maybe I can do that before building the html i will use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate over your array, saving the formatted strings to another array. You can pass the created array to your page and display it, or do whatever you want.

```
var json = "[{\"amount\":3,\"name\":\"Coca-Cola\"},{\"amount\":3,\"name\":\"Rib Eye\"}]",
    arr = JSON.parse(json),
    formatted = [];
arr.forEach(function(item) {
  formatted.push(item.amount + " - " + item.name);
});
```

In the above code, the array `formatted` contains the strings as you need them.